# Gnome fails to start in Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I've installed Debian Wheezy. After a while (working properly without any problem), I see some problems while working in gnome. Some functions don't work properly, for example desktop icons are not shown anymore and the option in dconf is unselected and disabled. And also all the staring chars in power off options like restart, hibernate and ... are shown as a squares.
After restart, gnome fails to start and only a terminal comes up.
Startx command only causes a blank screen and only a mouse pointer to be shown.

Also pressing ctrl+Alt+F7, doesn't have any effect, but the other ttys work fine.

This procedure has happened to me several times during this week and every time I had reinstalled all the OS again.
I was suspicious about my installation procedure or viruses. I did security updates.

Comment: Can you please use the `startx` command, and then post the output of `/var/log/XOrg.0.log`?

Comment: GNOME 3 should be started by `exec gnome-session`, not `startx`. BTW, are you using any GPU that requires property driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
I uninstalled the below packages:
gnome-session
gnome-shell

Make sure that the repository used is an online official source.
And reinstall both of them. While installing gnome-session, some version incompatibility errors may occure. Uninstall also them. They will be installed while installing gnome-session, don't worry.

Issue command:
sudo pam-auth-update --force
(Thanks to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugr...?bug=726773#10)

Reboot.

If it didn't start properly, before getting disappointed, try the procedure once again!

---

The error reason is because of version incompatibility for gtk3. Also there is a bug which caused pam configuraion to get currupted. The command pam-auth-update, updated the pam configuration properly.